# save-data-using-sales-order-model

Tags: ajax, magento2.3

I am sending ajax request to save data in my custom field in sales_order table , It saves data successfully in case of exit, but not with out exit, any suggestion

```
//Not working
public function updateCommentSection($order)
{     
    if ($order) {
            $orderId =  $order->getEntityId();
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 

            $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
            $order->setSkCanceledAt('13');
            $order->save();

        }
}


//Working
public function updateCommentSection($order)
{     
    if ($order) {
            $orderId =  $order->getEntityId();
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 

            $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
            $order->setSkCanceledAt('13');
            $order->save();
            exit;
        }
}
```

Comment: did you used return statement?

Comment: where is your method called from and what is the $order object you get as parameter? It might be that you are somewhere in the process where some other method which has loaded the order object before your method, is saving it after.

Comment: tried but not working

Comment: @HelgeB i get order object using $this->orderData->load($this->getOrderId());

Comment: So are you in a controller, observer or plugin?

Comment: I first tried this in observer , then in controller, same results

Comment: I don't know why in case of exit it works but not with out exit

Comment: the exit means that nothing else can save the order object after your action. For me it looks like the order object is already loaded in the process, you are loading it again and save it directly. The other order object loaded before does not have your data and is most probably saved after your code. If you hook in the observer `order_save_before`, implement some checks and just add your attribute value without saving the order, it should work

Comment: @sherazkhan are you looking to return any value to Ajax Request?

Comment: let me try this, I hope this will work, Thanks for your answer

Comment: @DhirenVasoya No i am returning none

Comment: So you can simple write return at the end of the code and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Order Object is already loaded in the process from where i call this function ,  I was loading it again and save it directly , The other object loaded before does not have my data which i was saving, after saving new data,my older order object overrides the new data of this function.